# VueJS error interactivity on class and styles

Tags: binding, vue.js

I meet an error on class reactivity and dot not find solution despite a lot of tests.

I modify data with local methods and it work but, application on this DOM (reactivity), does not exceed one. After one modification, the DOM is figed.

I use an Vue extend, i use $set to define value of attribute (because the extend of vue use an return object) or direct access, but the result always the same.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Jérémy

Comment: Include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're using, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's an exemple of code (i use webpack to build my vue app, javascript script separate to html).

```
<div id="modalMemberEdit" class="modal fade modalmember" v-bind:class="{ 'in':showmodal }" role="dialog" v-bind:style="{'display':displaymodal,'border':bordermodal}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" v-on:click="hideModal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-rouge" v-on:click="hideModal" ></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


const modalMemberEdit = Vue.extend({
    name: "modalMember",
    data: function () {
        return {
            displaymodal: "none",
            bordermodal: "15px solid white",
            showmodal: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showEditModal: function( id ) {
            this.$set(this._data,"showmodal",true);
            this.$set(this._data,"displaymodal","block");
        },
        hideModal: function() {

            this.$set(this._data,"showmodal",false);
            this.$set(this._data,"displaymodal","none");
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
       this.$set(this._data,"showmodal",true);
       this.$set(this._data,"displaymodal","block");
    }
});
```